# Ev3 classroom 1.5.2.0 not working

Tags: ev3, programming

When I try to create a new project or open an old project, the program does not work.

We have 10 computers (desktops) with different versions of Windows 10
[image]

Stuck on this.

Comment: Hi Martin and welcome to Bricks.SE! Can you please share more details concering your issue? Does "stuck on this" mean you can't advance from the depicted state? Can you see any error messages or can you use other functions?

Comment: We have the same issue. Similar set up.